# collection was mutated while being enumerated with coredata and multithreading

Tags: objective-c, ios, multithreading, ipad, core-data

I am trying to debug an ipad application I have just inherited from some other developers. At the moment I'm getting a really odd error that I'm not sure how to attack.

The app dies with this error:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSCFSet: 0xc5d2b40> was mutated while being enumerated.'

When I do po 0xc5d2b40, it tells me that its an array of a certain object type. However when I turn on breakpoints at all exceptions and go through the backtrace, there is no sign of an array of this object type being either enumerated or mutated.

I have seen a few references that suggest that this could be related to coredata and multithreading, but I'm wondering if anyone has any suggestions on how to approach this problem. I should also note: I ONLY get this error on the device, NOT in the simulator.

Thanks in advance!

Note: When the app hits the breakpoint from the objc_exception_throw, using the bt command I get the following results from the various background threads:

Most threads look like this:
tid = 0x2c03, 0x307e9cd4 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 8
    frame #0: 0x307e9cd4 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 8
    frame #1: 0x32d35f3c libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 616
    frame #2: 0x32d35cd0 libsystem_c.dylib`start_wqthread + 8

I have one thread which is running a method in the AFURLConnectionOperation (external library: AFNetworking).

There is a single thread with my code in the backtrace, which is what I referenced above. I'm a bit new to the debugger, am I potentially doing something wrong in checking my backtraces?

The backtrace on the thread where all my code is executing looks like this:

```
tid = 0x2003, 0x32d2fcac libsystem_c.dylib`OSSpinLockLock$VARIANT$wfe + 84
frame #0: 0x32d2fcac libsystem_c.dylib`OSSpinLockLock$VARIANT$wfe + 84
frame #1: 0x32eb7c88 libobjc.A.dylib`_objc_rootReleaseWasZero_slow + 28
frame #2: 0x32eb5210 libobjc.A.dylib`_objc_rootReleaseWasZero + 132
frame #3: 0x32eb515c libobjc.A.dylib`_objc_rootRelease + 12
frame #4: 0x31ba6b0a CoreData`-[NSSQLIntermediate _generateSQLForKeyPathExpression:allowToMany:inContext:] + 278
frame #5: 0x31ba687a CoreData`-[NSSQLIntermediate _generateSQLForExpression:allowToMany:inContext:] + 186
frame #6: 0x31babea4 CoreData`-[NSSQLSimpleWhereIntermediate _generateSQLType2InContext:] + 660
frame #7: 0x31ba6260 CoreData`-[NSSQLSimpleWhereIntermediate generateSQLStringInContext:] + 400
frame #8: 0x31bbbd06 CoreData`-[NSSQLCompoundWhereIntermediate _generateMulticlauseStringInContext:] + 174
frame #9: 0x31bbba84 CoreData`-[NSSQLCompoundWhereIntermediate generateSQLStringInContext:] + 272
frame #10: 0x31ba5d1a CoreData`-[NSSQLFetchIntermediate generateSQLStringInContext:] + 90
frame #11: 0x31ba24d0 CoreData`-[NSSQLGenerator newSQLStatementForFetchRequest:ignoreInheritance:countOnly:nestingLevel:] + 460
frame #12: 0x31ba2212 CoreData`-[NSSQLAdapter _newSelectStatementWithFetchRequest:ignoreInheritance:] + 414
frame #13: 0x31ba1e6c CoreData`-[NSSQLCore newRowsForFetchPlan:] + 144
frame #14: 0x31ba152e CoreData`-[NSSQLCore objectsForFetchRequest:inContext:] + 698
frame #15: 0x31ba0fc6 CoreData`-[NSSQLCore executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 282
frame #16: 0x31ba0464 CoreData`-[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 1432
frame #17: 0x31b9ec28 CoreData`-[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:] + 604
frame #18: 0x00052956 digidrill`-[DigidrillIncrementalCache executeFetchRequest:allNewerThanOrFailure:] + 410 at DigidrillIncrementalCache.m:80
frame #19: 0x0003fbae digidrill`-[DigidrillIncrementalStore(Responders) immutableCacheListResponderBegin:intoArray:inContext:outErr:] + 434 at DigidrillIncrementalStore+Responders.m:253
frame #20: 0x00015ea4 digidrill`-[DigidrillIncrementalStore executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 3836 at DigidrillIncrementalStore.m:157
frame #21: 0x31ba0464 CoreData`-[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 1432
frame #22: 0x31b9ec28 CoreData`-[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:] + 604
frame #23: 0x00018534 digidrill`+[CoreDataExtractor executeSyncFetchRequest:callback:onDispatchQueue:] + 704 at CoreDataExtractor.m:175
frame #24: 0x0001a9a2 digidrill`+[CoreDataExtractor ensureGammaDataExistsForTrack:maxOld:flags:outErr:] + 1234 at CoreDataExtractor.m:363
frame #25: 0x00058670 digidrill`-[XYGraph dataForTrackPlot:] + 632 at XYGraph.m:230
frame #26: 0x0006f7d6 digidrill`__23-[TrackPlot reloadData]_block_invoke_0 + 66 at TrackPlot.m:49
frame #27: 0x344b0c58 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
frame #28: 0x344b2d0e libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_queue_drain + 274
frame #29: 0x344b2b74 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 40
frame #30: 0x344b37e6 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_worker_thread2 + 210
frame #31: 0x32d35dfa libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 294
frame #32: 0x32d35cd0 libsystem_c.dylib`start_wqthread + 8
```

Comment: Have you followed the backtrace on all of the threads?

Comment: The error claims that it's a set rather than an array, which suggests that it **could** be related to a "to many" relationship.

Comment: Since it's only happening on the device, I'd suspect a threading issue. Probably one thread is enumerating the objects in a relationship while another updates them. NSManagedObject is not thread safe, so that is a significant error. Can you determine how other threads in your app are accessing the managed objects / managed object context and tell us more?

Comment: So I tried doing a backstack on each thread at the time the objc_exception was thrown and it *seems like* none of the other active threads had any of my code running at the time. I added the bt command result from the other threads in an edit to the main post.

Comment: You have an exception breakpoint yes? What's the stack trace of your code when that happens?

Comment: What's the Core Data threading architecture like in general? Have the people from whom you've inherited the project properly implemented thread confinement? Also which version of iOS is the device running?

Comment: (edited to include the stack trace from the main thread)

Comment: The challenge in this project is that its huge and extremely complex. The old programmers certainly knew what they were doing, so I assume they at least tried to keep the 1MOC per thread rule. That said, the complexity is sufficient that it is entirely possible they forgot one somewhere. I'm really just hoping to find a more systematic approach than searching line by line through hundreds of files for a missing MOC(especially if it turns out not to be related to that :) )

Comment: If that's really where the debugger says the exception is thrown, I'd look hard at your code (starting with the XYGraph method) and see if you're mutating anything there.

Comment: I see one enumeration a couple lines below where the exception was raised. Could that be related? I would think it would need to be something where the exception gets raised *inside* the enumeration?

Answer (score 3):

This guy has a pretty good explanation that solved it for me:

http://www.pixeldock.com/blog/collection-was-mutated-while-being-enumerated-during-coredata-operation-on-background-thread/

Basically the MO context can only be used by the thread on which it was created.